# Plausible Reasoning

Tags: probability, logic

I know $P(B|A)\geq P(B)$. I am now supposed to show that $P(B|\neg A)\leq P(B)$.
It seems trivial, but I can't figure out how to prove it.
A similar task I solved as follows:
To show $P(A|B)\geq P(A)$:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
$$\frac{P(A|B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$
As $P(B|A)\geq P(B)$, $\frac{P(B|A)}{P(B)}\geq 1$ so $\frac{P(A|B)}{P(A)}\geq 1$, hence $P(A|B)\geq P(A)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $0<P(A)<1$,

\begin{align}P(B\mid \neg A)P(\neg A)&=P(B\cap \neg A)=P(B)-P(B\cap A)=P(B)-P(B\mid A)P(A)\le\\&\le P(B)(1-P(A))=P(B)P(\neg A)\end{align}

Therefore $P(B\mid \neg A)\le P(B)$.